# How do you run package files with your application?

Tags: cocoa, packaging, directory, nsbundle

I have been building a Cocoa application and I've gotten most of the code worked out. At this point I have the application itself, a .command files to run some things from terminal, and a folder used to store files needed to run the .command properly. Is there a way to put the .command file and the folder inside the application and still run them? By inside I mean inside the package contents of the .app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/) to find the path to a file (or folder) inside your application bundle, or in any other bundle.

Comment: Can you show what the code would look like or how to use it? Im reading the link you included but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: @user981636: You'll need to send [this message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:) or one of the similar ones to [your main bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/mainBundle).